# Vector triple integral $\iiint_{D}(\vec a \cdot \vec R)(\vec b \cdot\vec R)(\vec c \cdot\vec R) \,dx\,dy\,dz=\frac{(\alpha\beta\gamma)^2}{8r}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Prove that

$$\iiint_{D}(\vec a \cdot \vec R)(\vec b \cdot\vec R)(\vec c \cdot\vec R) \,dx\,dy\,dz=\frac{(\alpha\beta\gamma)^2}{8r}$$

Where the $\vec a , \vec b,\vec c$ are constant vectors, $\vec R=x \hat i+y\hat j+z\hat k$ is the position vector.

The region is defined as 
$$D: \begin{cases}0 \le \vec a \cdot\vec R \le \alpha,\\ 0 \le\vec b \cdot\vec R \le \beta,\\ 0 \le \vec c \cdot\vec R \le \gamma\end{cases}$$

And $r$ is the volume of the parallelepiped with sides $\vec a,\vec b,\vec c$.

Please help. I don't know how. I tried to do transformation of coordinates and use jacobian but I cannot prove it. I think it is impossible to do with what I have been taught. It also appears in Stewarts chapter 15 Problems Plus, number 4

Comment: Your notation is confusing. I can't tell where are vectors and where are scalars in your post

Comment: Sorry because I tried to use \hat and \widehat and no matter what I did I kept getting something that will not render

Comment: @PersonaA Use `\vec` ${}{}$. I tried to make your question look clearer. Also, the `\hat` command works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be an easy way to solve this problem, but if you don't know it, just do it the hard way.

Expand the scalar products:

$$(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{R})=a_x x+a_y y+a_z z$$

The definition of the region gives you the complete information to find the boundaries for $x,y,z$:

For lower boundaries $x_1,y_1,z_1$ you need to solve the following system of equations:

$$a_x x_1+a_y y_1+a_z z_1=0$$
$$b_x x_1+b_y y_1+b_z z_1=0$$
$$c_x x_1+c_y y_1+c_z z_1=0$$

In this case the only solution is $(0,0,0)$.

For upper boundaries $x_2,y_2,z_2$ you need to solve the following system of equations:

$$a_x x_2+a_y y_2+a_z z_2=\alpha$$
$$b_x x_2+b_y y_2+b_z z_2=\beta$$
$$c_x x_2+c_y y_2+c_z z_2=\gamma$$

Since all the boundaries are constant, the region is a parallelepiped, so the triple integral clearly separates.

Once you found the boundaries, expand the function under the integral and solve it the usual way:

$$\int^{x_2}_{x_1} \int^{y_2}_{y_1} \int^{z_2}_{z_1} (a_x x+a_y y+a_z z)(b_x x+b_y y+b_z z)(c_x x+c_y y+c_z z) dx dy dz$$

I warn you though, this is very long computation to do by hand, so there has to be an easier way.

Also, volume of parallelepiped on three vectors is given by:

$$r=|\vec{a} \cdot (\vec{b} \times \vec{c}) |=|\vec{c} \cdot (\vec{a} \times \vec{b}) |=|\vec{b} \cdot (\vec{c} \times \vec{a}) |$$